# How to run a python script in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a hello.py file located in "/home/user1/public_html/cgi-bin" that displays the python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import platform

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print(platform.python_version())
```

When I go to the url for the script, it displays "2.6.6" in the browser.

I am wanting to use python 3.5 so I had the webhost install a virtualenv in "/home/user1/virtualenv/testproject/"

When I try to change the first line of the code to:

```
#!/home/user1/virtualenv/testproject/3.5/bin/python

import platform

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print(platform.python_version())
```

the script will display "It works! Python 3.5.5" which is not what I have coded into the script.

Am I supposed to put the hello.py file into the virtualenv directory?  Or is it that I have the path to the python 3.5 incorrect?  Or am I just totally misunderstanding how all of this works?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you activate the virtual env?

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3, so you must call it: `print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")`. print-as-operator is a SyntaxError in Python 3.

Comment: @phd it works after changing it to what you said.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phd's comment was the correct answer.  `print` is a function in Python 3, so you must call it: `print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")`. print-as-operator is a SyntaxError in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely resolve your problem

Your Code is correct nothing to worry because it will gives correct output in interpreter.

This problem is happening because you installed two versions of python on your machine and by default the path of python 2 is set in the priority in your Environment Variable.

The Script gives correct output in interpreter because priority of path is not required for interpreter but when you run it from browser or command-prompt or console then path is required and it search the path of python from system environment variable.In your case, First it got the path of python 2 ,so that its show the version of python 2

Their will be two solution for your problem, You can do anyone.

1. Uninstall python 2 from your system. This will resolve your problem instantly.
2. If you want to keep both version of python then for resolving this problem you should have to set the path of python 3 in the priority from environment variable. Like This

See in the Screenshot, Path of Python 2 is Upper in the Environment Variable should be below the Path of Python 3

[image: See in the Screenshot, Path of Python 2 is Upper in the Environment Variable should be below the Path of Python 3]

Like This

This is the correct and static way to set the path in priority
[image: This is the correct and static way to set the path in priority]
Thank you, Expecting This will resolve your problem